# JNI - "Cannot open include file: 'jni_md.h'"

Tags: java, c, compiler-errors, java-native-interface

This sample program is meant to call a `native` method written in C.

**Java Code**

```
class HelloWorld {

    private native void print();

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        new HelloWorld().print();
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
    }

}
```

After writing this i compiled the program and generated a `JNI` style header file.

**The header file generated is :**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: ()V
 */
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print
 (JNIEnv *, jobject);

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
 #endif
```

**And the native method written in c**

```
#include <C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\jni.h>
#include <C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32\jni_md.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print( JNIENv *env , jobject obj) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return;
}
```

The error I get on compiling is `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jni_md.h': No such file or directory`

Also my compiler underlines `jobject obj` saying that `this class does not have storage class or specifier` . It underlines `*env` saying `expected a ')'`.

Why do I get this error ?

Comment: You have no such file or directory. Check?

Comment: @ Daniel It is there. `include` statement does not give an error

Comment: You have <C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32\jni_md.h>, but not "jni_md.h". Check what headers include what; more specifically, what header includes "jni_md.h". EDIT: See Stuart Cooks answer.

Comment: @ Daniel i cannot understand this.

Comment: please use a more descriptive title for your question

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I suspect that `jni.h` is trying to `#include <jni_md.h>`, which is then failing because you haven't added its location to your include path.

Try adding both of these entries to your C compiler's include path:

- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include`
- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32`

The `win32` path might not be necessary, depending on how `jni.h` is set up.

Comment: I have added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include` to the include directories of  my project and then i also i get the same error

Comment: Did you add both lines? Check in `jni.h` to see how it includes `jni_md.h`.

Comment: I have tried either ways : adding `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\Win32` and not adding the path.But it does not solve my problem

Comment: I had this problem on linux. The `jni_md.h` file was in my java `includes/linux` folder, I had to manually create a link (shortcut) to the includes/ folder to fix this issue. On windows, you can try adding a shortcut file to that file.

Comment: Had same problem on Mac OSX. File path is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin/jni_md.h

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

HelloWorld.c

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return;
}
```

Compile it using cl.exe (I'm using VC++ and CL.EXE required following command line switches.)

> c:\>cl -c /I"c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\include" /I"c:\Prog
>   ram Files\java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32" HelloWorld.c

Link .obj module

> c:\>link /libpath="c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\lib" HelloWorld.obj /dll

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but where can I download `cl.exe` package (I need only the command-line compiler, libs+headers)? Thanks.

Comment: @dma_k  You can download Visual C++ 2010 Express (It is free) - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Answer (score 1):

A Simple Java Native Interface (JNI) example in Java

- env：**jdk8、macOS 10.15**

```
// Main.java
public class Main {
    public native int intMethod(int i);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Main");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Main().intMethod(2));
    }
}
```

```c
// Main.c:
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_intMethod(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i)
{
    return i * i;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
javac Main.java -h .
gcc -dynamiclib -O3 \
    -I/usr/include \
    -I$JAVA_HOME/include \
    -I$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin \
    Main.c -o libMain.dylib
java -cp . -Djava.library.path=$(pwd) Main
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once, my solution was actually to edit the jni.h's internal #include from 
    `"jni_md.h"` to `"win32/jni_md.h"`, although there is probably a less hacky way you are supposed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the following header file in your native code first

```
#include <jni.h>
```

In my case in UNIX system,

- This header file `jni.h` is present at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/`
- Also, `jni_md.h` is present at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux`

You can get the path to above files if you know where the Java installation path redirects you in your system. Get it done by following set of commands.

```
whereis java
/usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

ls -l /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

where (->) is symbolic link.

- At last, you get your Java installation path. In my case, it is
  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

> Also don't forget to include `jni.h` & `jni_md.h` files path while
>   doing their native Compilation.

**Compilation**:-

```
gcc -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/ -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/ -o libHelloWorld.so -shared *nativeSourceCodeFile*.c
```

where (-I) is Identify the Path.

- Above command compiles our native code & that's why path of Java
  Native Interface header file `jni.h` is provided in reference.
- `jni.h` does the explicit import of `jni_md.h` ie. `#include "jni_md.h"` & that's why we've provided next reference in our compilation to that `jni_md.h` file.
- `jni_md.h` contains the machine-dependent typedefs for jbyte, jint and jlong.

**Execution**:-

```
java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
```

---

Next,

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print( JNIEnv* env , jobject obj){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Just see the small changes made and try to implement it.