# Python with Java, PyJNIus installation

Tags: java, python, pyjnius

In order to use Java with bindings in Python, am installing, the following:
https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius

I got this error: it seems trying to compile C++ file header into the Java_HOME.... , which looks very strange:

```
    Installing collected packages: jnius
      Running setup.py install for jnius
        Complete output from command D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='f:\\usertemp\\pip-build-wdmlwj\\jnius\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record f:\usertemp\pip-f_a0kd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        running build_ext
        skipping 'jnius\jnius.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
        building 'jnius' extension
        D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\Scripts\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IE:\_devs\JDK7\include -IE:\_devs\JDK7\include\linux -ID:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\include -ID:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\PC -c jnius\jnius.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\jnius\jnius.o
        In file included from jnius\jnius.c:256:0:
        E:\_devs\JDK7\include/jni.h:45:20: fatal error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory
         #include "jni_md.h"
                            ^
        compilation terminated.
        error: command 'D:\\_devs\\Python01\\WinPython-64-2710\\python-2.7.10.amd64\\Scripts\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: That is probably C, not C++.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [JNI - “Cannot open include file: 'jni_md.h'”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212982/jni-cannot-open-include-file-jni-md-h)?

Comment: ok, Am investigating this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212982/jni-cannot-open-include-file-jni-md-h

Answer (score 0):

Well based on the error I think there is an issue with missing parts of the required packages for Python to Compile the Jnius extension in Windows OS, being honest, in Windows you will find more errors than Ubuntu, I do not know why, I switched from Windows to Ubuntu, and now, programming is better and easy, but here is a workaround:

In Ubuntu, I know the commands to do this, but for windows, take a look here:
https://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

And here:
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/11/05/install-gcc-windows/

The best suggestion I can give you is, install Latest Stable Ubuntu Official Software, there is no need to uninstall Windows you can have both, Ubuntu and Windows