# C++ compilation error for JNI: unknown type name JNIEnv jint JavaVM

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, g++

I'm getting a compilation error for the following header file:

```
#include <jni.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    jint x1;
    jint y1;
    jint x2;
    jint y2;
} Bounds;

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

There are other JNI references, such as to `jobject`, `JNIEnv`, `JavaVM`, etc.
It's not complaining that the <jni.h> header is missing (it was, but that was easily fixed by adding the include path). I've checked the header file and the types are defined in that header (and <jni_md.h> too).

This isn't making any sense to me. Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to include the following error text.

```
g++ -O2 -fPIC -fpermissive -I. -I.. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice -I/usr/local/include/libavformat -I/usr/local/include/libswscale -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers -DUNIX -shared -c -o Plugin.o Plugin.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-shared'
In file included from Plugin.cpp:19:
In file included from Plugin.h:16:
Data.h:24:5: error: unknown type name 'jint'
    jint x1;
    ^
Data.h:25:5: error: unknown type name 'jint'
    jint y1;
    ^
Data.h:26:5: error: unknown type name 'jint'
    jint x2;
    ^
Data.h:27:5: error: unknown type name 'jint'
    jint y2;
    ^
```

Comment: Will you please include the full error text?

Comment: May be - see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212982/

Comment: @ZabojCampula like I said I'm not having an issue with finding the headers, they're being included.

Comment: @GuyKogus: ok, so I repeat Leon's question: what is exactly the compiler error?

Comment: I just added it now :)

Comment: What is `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers`? That looks nothing like any JDK header path I've ever seen.  You're not relying on some *copy* of a JDK's header files?

Comment: I tried from other locations too, like from the JDK I downloaded to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/include`, and then I also need to include `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin` to find <jni_md.h>, but I got the exact same error.

Comment: I'm really suspicious of your build environment and/or `Plugin.cpp` source code. Per the source code at http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/, if you're getting the proper `jni.h` and `jni_md.h`, you should not be seeing those errors.  What's in your `Plugin.cpp` file?

Comment: Try to compile with option `-E` to see the preprocessor result. Perhaps you find a hint there. May be the headers are found in different location than you expect or whatever. BTW do you use `clang` or `gcc`? The command line contains the command `g++` but the warning looks like from clang.

Comment: @ZabojCampula You got it, thank you! Looking at the preprocessor result I could see that the jni.h file it was including wasn't the correct one. libavcodec, one of the libraries I reference, has its own jni.h file that was being taken instead. By changing the include ordering I got it to work. Write your suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @GuyKogus In hindsight, this is really relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834778/how-to-tell-where-a-header-file-is-included-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C code does not have any obvious error and it is compilable if the development environment is correctly set up. So the suspected area is the development environment and that is probably missing or corrupted JNI header files.

The C compiler provides the option `-E` which and compiler runs preprocessor only when the option is applied. The output might be analyzed contains locations where the header files was found expanded ifdefs and so on.

The preprocessor output shows the wrong `jni.h` file was included. The solution is to properly setup the project include paths the include the correct `jni.h`.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, indeed.

You can take a look at very similar code, that compiles just fine here:

```
https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025
```

Just one remark in your case. While you compile your code, don't use

```
-shared
```

You should use it while building shared library:

```
# compile the code
g++ -O2 -fPIC -fpermissive -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers -DUNIX -c -o c/recipeNo025_HelloWorld.o c/recipeNo025_HelloWorld.cpp

# make shared lib out of it
g++ -g -shared c/recipeNo025_HelloWorld.o -o lib/libHelloWorld.$(EXT)
```